# Is it safe to convert a pointer to typed/sized enum to a pointer to the underlying type?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, enums, implicit-conversion

The following code:

```
void f(const uint8_t* a) {}  // <- this is an external library function
enum E : uint8_t { X, Y, Z };

int main(void) {
  E e = X;
  f(&e);  // <- error here
}
```

Produces the following error:

```
/tmp/c.cc:10:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
  f(&e);
  ^
/tmp/c.cc:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'E *' to 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') for 1st argument
void f(const uint8_t* e) { }
```

Which is surprising to me because I thought the `: uint8_t` in the enum's definition would mean they are necessarily represented with that underlying type. I can easily get around this with a cast:

```
f((uint8_t*)&e);
```

which I don't mind too much, but given that it's an error to omit it, is this always safe or is the `: uint8_t` not providing the guarantees I think it is?

Comment: You'd want that to be an error. If the function in question assigns values outside the range of your `enum`, would you want that to just happen? It's like saying it's a good idea to allow, without casting, passing `int*` to a function that expects `unsigned*`; sure, they're usually the same size, but even then, half the range of one has completely different meaning for the other.

Comment: And you probably break strict aliasing rule with your cast.

Comment: `e` exists in memory as an uint8_t so the cast must be safe.

Comment: Except that its a rather bad design it's an interesting question. @ShadowRanger Note that OP doesn't use the value. And the result is unspecified (since c++17 it's UB) only when converting from the underlying type to the enum for value which does not have coverage in the enum type. And OP isn't even casting enum type, but the address.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect actual use-case, which I don't believe is bad design nor suffers from the problem @ShadowRanger mentions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed safe (although I'm not a language-lawyer): What's stored in memory is a `uint8_t`, and that's what you'll be pointing at. However, if `f()` were to take a pointer to a non-const `uint8_t`, then it could potentially change the value to something that's not explicitly defined as one of the `E` enum values. **(Edit:)** While this is apparently allowed by the C++ standard, it is surprising to many (see discussion in the comments below on this point), and I would encourage you to ensure it does not happen.

... but as others suggest, you're not getting the error because of your notion of safety, but because implicit conversions aren't performed between pointed-to types. You can pass an `E` to a function taking a `uint8_t`, but not an `E *` to a function taking a `uint8_t *`; that would be - according to the language committee and in my opinion as well - an overly cavalier attitude to pointer types.

Comment: "then it could potentially change the value to something that's not a valid `E` value" -- In enumerations with an explicit underlying type, aren't all values of the underlying type also valid for the enum?

Comment: @hvd: I don't think so, no. The only valid elements of an `enum E` are those specifically defined in it, and AFAIK this is not effected by specifying the underlying type.

Comment: "For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type." (n4140 [dcl.enum]p8)

Comment: @hvd: Really? I wouldn't have guessed that's the case. Are you sure the second-to-last "the" in that sentence isn't in there by mistake?

Comment: @einpoklum: The representation in memory doesn't really matter if the compiler performs optimizations based on the aliasing rules of the language. For scoped enums (which have the same memory representations) I actually had a case where g++'s optimizer did this. The reason why many compilers might not consider normal enums as a different type from the underlying one is imho for historical reasons and because the C language is less resttrictive.

Comment: @einpoklum: Enum variables are absolutely allowed to assume values for which there exists not constant.  E.g.`gsl::byte` is defined as a scoped enum without any elements.

Comment: @MikeMB: I re-edited based on yours and hvd's comments, but, frankly - I have to admit I have always assumed enum variables only have values of explicitly-defined elements (unless I reinterpret-cast). It's a bit shocking to me that this is not the case officially. That's essentially saying that enums are nothing but a glorified way to define constants.

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, I was pretty suprised myself, but afaik thats exactly what they where originally designed for.

Comment: @MikeMB: That doesn't seem to make sense. I mean, enums without a specified underlying type were not designed for this, and the sentence you quoted seems to also imply  "for an enumeration whose underlying type is _not_ fixed, it is _not_ the case that the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type" - but really, I find it hard to believe that specifying the underlying type should affect the semantics that much. That's why this is an incredible sentence to me.

Comment: @einpoklum For enums without a fixed underlying type, not all values of the underlying type are valid, but more than just the enumerator values: bitwise or of two enumerator values always produces a value that can be stored in the enumeration type as well. This is essential for enumerator values that are used as flags. As for "originally" -- in C, from the first standard to even today, `enum E { E1, E2 }; enum E e; unsigned *p = &e;` is perfectly valid. Enumerator types are "compatible with" an implementation-dependent integer type, and all values that are valid in one are valid in the other.

Comment: @hvd: IIRC, enums are not guaranteed to have an `int`-sized storage in C.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry for not being clearer, character limit. Enumerator types in C are "compatible with" an implementation-dependent integer type, which on my implementation for that particular `enum E` is `unsigned`. That's why `int *p = &e;` is invalid on my implementation due to the incompatible pointer type and can cause an error, but `unsigned *p = &e;` does not even trigger a warning. On other implementations, it may be `int *p = &e;` that's valid, or any of `short`, `unsigned short`, `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`, or perhaps even some extended integer type.

Answer (score 6):

**Afaik this is only legal by accident:**

What you are doing is performing a `reinterpret_cast` and I'm assuming `f` is dereferencing that pointer internally. This is only legal in a very restricted set of cases and while not normative, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) gives a good overview of those:

> When a pointer or reference to object whose dynamic type is DynamicType is reinterpret_cast (or C-style cast) to a pointer or reference to object of a different type AliasedType, the cast always succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be used to access the object if one of the following is true:
>
> - AliasedType is (possibly cv-qualified) DynamicType
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are both (possibly multi-level, possibly cv-qualified at each level) pointers to the same type T (since C++11)
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType
> - AliasedType is an aggregate type or a union type which holds one of the aforementioned types as an element or non-static member (including, recursively, elements of subaggregates and non-static data members of the contained unions): this makes it safe to obtain a usable pointer to a struct or union given a pointer to its non-static member or element.
> - AliasedType is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of DynamicType and DynamicType is a standard-layout class that has has no non-static data members, and AliasedType is its first base class.
> - AliasedType is char, unsigned char, or std::byte: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.
>
> If AliasedType does not satisfy these requirements, accessing the object through the new pointer or reference invokes undefined behavior. This is known as the strict aliasing rule and applies to both C++ and C programming languages.

None of those cases includes casting to a pointer to an enum's underlying type!

**However:**
Casting to a pointer to `unsigned char*` and dereferencing it is always legal and on most platforms `uint8_t` is just a typedef for that. So it is ok in this case, but wouldn't be if the underlying type e.g. would be a `uint16_t`.

That being said, I would not be surprised to hear that most compilers would allow such usage, even if the standard does not.

Comment: Actually [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is defined as `enum class byte : unsigned char {};`, and the `reinterpret_cast` is legal according to the last point.

Comment: I donn't see the relevance. The last point says you can cast pointers to std::byte - not to std::uint8_t, which is a distinct type.